# AWS CloudFront website crashes once per month with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an AWS Cloud Front Distribution linked to a static S3 bucket in order to serve a website over HTTPS. **Everything works fine.**

However approximately **once per month, the website will go down**. No errors are reported, and the S3 bucket is still serving fine. The browser gives the warning `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` as seen in the image below. I have tried and tested all client side issues (different internet, browser, terminal, computer)

**In order to fix the issue, I have to `disable` and `enable` the cloud front distribution again.**

I was wondering whether anyone else has experienced this issue, and has some suggestions on navigating around it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with different browser, different computer, or different internet connection to rule out any issues on client-side? You can also try `curl -I <URL>` to see the actual response from the server.

Comment: Yup, all client side issues tried and tested

Comment: "cozie.app" isn't running through CloudFront and S3, it's running through Fastly and Github.  Did you move it?

Comment: Yea I eventually had to move it because the crashing was causing problems for communications team